# Can someone help me identifying similar diagram?

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Can someone help me identifying similar diagram?

Given diagram is used as [Show that the sequence is non decreasing.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050479/show-that-the-sequence-is-non-decreasing)

Comment: Instead of having the top-left corners of the rectangles touch the graph, have the top-right corners touch the graph.

Comment: @AlexZorn, you mean by shifting the curve by 1, right?

Comment: I mean shrinking the rectangles, though shifting the curve should also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Consider the *lower Riemann sums* for the function $\dfrac1x$.